# Помогите дополнить код

Tags: c++, массивы

Помогите пожалуйста дополнить код.
Задача: Задать одномерный массив размерностью 10 элементов с первым элементом 0 (фиксированный) с вводом всех остальных символов, посчитать количество парных нулей и вывести на экран.
Нужно зафиксировать первый элемент сделав его 0, и посчитать количество парных нулей, смог задать только что бы считало по 1 нулю.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int N;
cin >> N;
int arr[10] = {};
do arr[N%10]++;
while (N/=10);
cout << arr[0];
}
```

Comment: Не понимаю о чем вы, при запуске в компиляторе нужно ввести символы и из 10 символов считает количество 0

Comment: У вас вводится одно число. Покажите пример данных, и что должно быть в результате.

Comment: Вводиться массив состоящий из 10 чисел и считается количество нулей из этого массива. Например число 45103620. Количество нулей:2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас в описании вопроса одно условие, в комментарии другое, надо бы определиться. Попробуйте начать с такого примера:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    // Задать одномерный массив размерностью 10 элементов
    int arr[10] = {};

    int zero_count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        // Вводиться массив состоящий из 10 чисел
        cin >> arr[i];
        // считается количество нулей из этого массива
        if (arr[i] == 0)
            zero_count++;
    }

    // и вывести на экран
    cout << "Zero count: " << zero_count;
}
```

Comment: Количество "парных нулей", видимо, автору и не особо нужно

Comment: @MBo, ага, как обычно))